# I would like to avoid importing duplicates records but ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in dbf file.

I am writing PHP script to import data from dbf file to the mysql using PHP and ODBC connection.

So I have file called ffc. It has four columns file, format,commons,dbf. The dbf file does not have primary key.

I created a table in mysql with 4 fields. I also added an 'id' field as primary key.

I am writing PHP to import records from dbf file to the mysql. But if records exist update (if record has been updated in dbf file) and move to next records and add new record if record does not exist.

I am using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE file` but it is not working. 
WHen I run the script first time; all records get imported. But when I run the script again they get imported again.

Here is code.

```
<?php require_once('../database.php'); ?>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

//ODBC connection
$connectionstring = odbc_connect("foxpro", "", "");

//Select statement to pull data 
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM ffc.dbf";
$rw  = odbc_exec($connectionstring, $q1);

//Loop through to insert data into mysql
while ($rs = odbc_fetch_array($rw)) {
   //print_r($rs);
     $file =  $rs['file'];
     $format =  $rs['format'];
     $commons =  $rs['commons'];
     $dbf =  $rs['dbf'];


//Insert/Update query
$test_query = "INSERT INTO test (file, format, commons, dbf) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE file = ?, format = ?, commons = ?, dbf = ?;";

if(!($stmt_test_query = $mysqli->prepare($test_query))) {
    echo "Prepare (1) failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if(!($stmt_test_query->bind_param('iiiiiiii', $file, $format, $commons, $dbf,$file, $format, $commons, $dbf))) {
    echo "Bind params (1) failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if(!($stmt_test_query->execute())) {
    echo "Execute (1) failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
} 



}
?>
```

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` doesn't do anything unless you insert duplicate values into a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in your table. It doesn't know that the other columns should be constrained to be unique unless there's a table constraint to make that true.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin. The remote (external) table does not have primary key. In my case what would be the best solution to insert/update records

Comment: If you want the combination of file, format, commons, dbf to be unique, then `ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE KEY (file, format, commons, dbf)`. But if those columns are long varchars, you may not be able to make a single key out of them, because there's a length limit on keys in MySQL.

Comment: By the way, you might like to avoid binding your parameters twice if you use this syntax: `INSERT INTO test (file, format, commons, dbf) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE file = VALUES(file), format = VALUES(format), commons = VALUES(commons), dbf = VALUES(dbf);` That will re-use each value you tried to insert.

Comment: I tired '"ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE Key" that didn't worked.